# Loading template from an external URL in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an HTML template stored in a VPS. I want to use this template for rendering in Django, is there a way to do this? 
I know its better to have the template in the same project directory as Django, but I am just curious to know how can I render a template which is not in our project folder and we know its url.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. For you can for example use the **`requests`** library to obtain the template code, and then construct the template:

```
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template, Context

def some_view(request):
    import requests
    url = 'http://my.url.com/templates/some_template.html'
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    
    template = Template(response.content)
    
    context = Context({
        'some_element': 42,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

So we here first fetch the template data, then we construct a `Template` object, and we can then `template.render(..)` it with a given `context`, and `request`, and for example wrap the rendered text inot a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Thanks, willem for the response, is there some way that Django provides for such cases, like modifying Django's template loader?

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad: as far as I know, no. But you can wrap this logic in some utility functions (and thus define your own shortcuts).